# Does a class need to be instantiated for you to read one of its properties?

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have an interface

```
public interface IType{
    string property1 {get;}
}
```

and two classes that implement it

```
public class concrete1 : IType{

    public string property1 {get {return "testing1";}}
}
public class concrete2 : IType{

    public string property1 {get {return "testing2";}}
}
```

Can I isolate which class contains the string "testing2" without instantiating either classes?  So that I can instantiate only that specific one.

Comment: I don't have an apple. Is the apple red? Perhaps, if it's a static apple.

Comment: lol, that's what I was thinking, but was curious if anyone knew any magic

Comment: It sounds like there might be an easier way to meet your end goal. It might be time to revisit your design. What problem are you actually trying to solve? My brain is screaming "Factory Pattern" right now, but you haven't really given enough information to be sure.

Comment: your properties are instance properties so yes you have to create instances in order to get values of those properties.

Comment: I'm trying to search a text for the string that matches the pattern defined by a class, then instantiate the class and execute the method specific to that string -- yes factory pattern is where I was headed

Comment: There's not much to say to this question rather than "yes". If you explain your design goal we might be able to tell you a way to achieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does.

An object only contains data if it's instantiated. Even if you define a property as above, you still need to instantiate it. If you make a static property, however, you will be able to access it by calling concrete1.property1, etc.

I don't believe you can define a static property against an interface, however.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot reference instance members (like that property) without an instance of the class. You will need to make that property `static` to get it without the instance.